# Sharepoint email with presence

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

On the SharePoint I have set Email Column to Email with presence and it works on the out of the box form on SharePoint but when I create an edit form ".aspx" in sharepoint designer that column does not have Email with presence feature. There will be a contact book icon, you have to click there and add their emails like that. That takes up so much time so I was wondering if I can change something on edit.

Please help!!!